# No Flash messages are displayed after redirect

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a basic plugin where I create some data when a user fills out form.
When the user enter a email which is already used I add a flash message and forward him back to the same form.
This works.

But after everything is OK I redirect the user to an another page, there I would like to show an another flash message like "Account created". But the Flash message is not being displayed at all.

Setting and redirectit this way:

```php
$this->addFlashMessage('Account created', null, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::OK, true);
$this->redirect(null, null, null, null, $this->settings["loginPageUid"]);
```

Render this way:

`<f:flashMessages />`

Did I miss something?
Setting the Flash message and showing it is inside the same extension/plugin, it's also the same view.

typo3 version 9

Comment: Can you verify that a FE session is created?

Comment: How could I verify it?

Comment: Check if the plugin is cached. Only uncached show the flash message.

Comment: Add action in non-cachable action list in the  `configurePlugin` section, take a look in your `ext_localconf.php`

Comment: Yes they are uncached and I think I found the isseu. AFAIS the cookie "fe_typo_user" is the session identifier for the cookies. We thought that thiscookie is only relevant when I use peform a Frontend login, and we delete it after the process. I think we have to find an another way to check if the user is logged in in the frontend.

Comment: Just for completion, I found the reason. We have an method in our controller for logging out the user which gets called after the process. Inside the methode we delte the `fe_typo_user`cookie which leads to the error that the flash message is not display. Instead of deleting the cookie we no use the propepr way to logout a user via `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->logoff(); $GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 0;`Now the flash messages appear

Comment: Have same problem but for Backend, on one instance all work fine other two don't show FleshMessages.  On same server). Have no clue why

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that we deleted the cookie `fe_typo_user` on a completly different place because we thought that's the correct way to log out a user. But this cookie is also used for the Flash message session.

Now we us:

```php
GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->logoff();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 0;
```

to log him out and didn't touch the cookie at all.